# rewriterule with multiple domains apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I need rewrite rule for following

https://dev-accessories-**abc**.km.com  --> https://dev-accessories-**abc**.km.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/**abc**-us

**abc** is the variable here. **abc** can be replaced with **efg** or **kml** to create multiple domain.

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? A quick search online should turn up some straightforward results, so presumably you've had problems with them?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev-accessories-(.*)\.km\.com$
# to prevent loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/%1
RewriteRule ^ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/%1-us [L]
```

?